# extJS RadioGroup setValue() function

Tags: extjs, radio-group, setvalue

I have created RadioGroup using the code

```
var radios = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
     columns    : 2,
       items: [
             {boxLabel: 'E-Mail', name: 'communication', inputValue: 1},
             {boxLabel: 'Nagios', name: 'communication', inputValue: 2}
        ]
   });
```

I want to check one of the radio button on some event. How to do it?
I tried using:

```
radios.setValue(true, false);
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

radios.items.items should return you the radio buttons inside the radio group. You can then use the setValue() function on them to check or uncheck them.

```
radios.items.items[index].setValue(true/false);
```

Comment: but how do we use RadioGroup's setValue()? this works for individual ones but what about the overall group

Answer (score 14):

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup-method-setValue

```
var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title       : 'RadioGroup Example',
    width       : 300,
    bodyPadding : 10,
    renderTo    : Ext.getBody(),
    items       : [
        {
            xtype      : 'radiogroup',
            fieldLabel : 'Group',
            items      : [
                { boxLabel : 'Item 1', name : 'rb', inputValue : 1 },
                { boxLabel : 'Item 2', name : 'rb', inputValue : 2 }
            ]
        }
    ],
    tbar        : [
        {
            text    : 'setValue on RadioGroup',
            handler : function () {
                // Set the value of the 'rb' radio butons
                var val = {rb : 2};
                form.child('radiogroup').setValue(val);
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 6):

to select 'E-Mail',for example

```
radios.setValue({communication: 1});
```

General use:

```
radioGroup_var.setValue({radioGroup_name: 'inputValue'});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
radios.setValue({communication:<input value>});
```

Where *input value* could be the value of the **inputValue** field of the radio button

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an array of values to the setValue method like so:

```
radios.setValue([true, false]);
```

This will work in ExtJs 3.x not sure about ExtJs4 check the [api](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but Google always finds this first, so I'll just throw my solution (on Ext 3.4.1.1) in here.

Try this:

```
var radios = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
    columns: 2,
    name: 'communication', // <== ADD THE NAME AGAIN ON HERE
    items: [
        {boxLabel: 'E-Mail', name: 'communication', inputValue: 1},
        {boxLabel: 'Nagios', name: 'communication', inputValue: 2}
    ]
});
```

`radios.setValue(2);` or for a bigger form panel  `formPanel.getForm().setValues([{communication: 2}])`
should work now.